# Performance drop loop vs iterator

Tags: performance, loops, kotlin

I am using kotlin in combination with lwjgl. So far I had the following code that ran several thousand times per second:

```
// val textureMap = HashMap<Int, Texture>()
fun bind() {
    var index = 0
    for(entry in textureMap) {
        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0 + index)
        entry.value.bind()
        program.setInt(entry.key, index)
        ++index
    }
}
```

So while this was running absolutely fast and consumed virtually 0 of my frame time as expected I had to replace it because it created an `Iterator` in every call, eventually leading to tens of thousands of those objects eventually getting garbage collected and halting my program for a few milliseconds which is of course not usable in my application.

So I went ahead and changed it to the following code:

```
// textures = ArrayList<Texture>()
// indices = ArrayList<Int>()
fun bind() {
    var index = 0
    while(index < textures.size) {
        val uniform = indices[index]
        val texture = textures[index]
        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0 + index)
        texture.bind()
        program.setInt(uniform, index)
        ++index
    }
}
```

Now for some reason I am noticing a massive drop in performance, namely the function now uses several seconds per frame. Using `jvisualvm` I was able to determine that all that time is spent in `glActiveTexture` in the native part as well as the native function in `program.setInt(...)`. I am absolutely stumped why this is the case, especially after comparing the byte code of the two.

This is the decompiled class file for the first (fast) version:

```
public final void bind()
{
  int index = 0;
  Map localMap = (Map)this.textureMap;
  for (Map.Entry entry : localMap.entrySet())
  {
    GL13.glActiveTexture(33984 + index);
    ((Texture)entry.getValue()).bind(); Program 
      tmp66_63 = this.program;
    if (tmp66_63 == null) {
      Intrinsics.throwUninitializedPropertyAccessException("program");
    }
    tmp66_63.setInt(((Number)entry.getKey()).intValue(), index);
    index++;
  }
}
```

And that is the byte code of the slow version:

```
public final void bind()
{
  int index = 0;
  while (index < this.textures.size())
  {
    Integer uniform = (Integer)this.indices.get(index);
    Texture texture = (Texture)this.textures.get(index);
    GL13.glActiveTexture(33984 + index);
    texture.bind(); Program 
      tmp52_49 = this.program;
    if (tmp52_49 == null) {
      Intrinsics.throwUninitializedPropertyAccessException("program");
    }
    Integer tmp62_61 = uniform;Intrinsics.checkExpressionValueIsNotNull(tmp62_61, "uniform");tmp52_49.setInt(tmp62_61.intValue(), index);
    index++;
  }
}
```

I am extremely confused what is going on here. In both versions the call to `glActiveTexture` is `GL_TEXTURE0 + <an int value>`, yet one takes so much more time thatn the other.

Does anyone have an idea what I am missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Basically my entire question can be removed. I should have debugged and not only profiled. The problem was the code that populated the lists, and it didnt remove the old values so the lists grew larger and larger and the loop just ran so many more times over time...

In case anyone was wondering how I fixed my problem with the allocations I essentially created two collections, one is containing the uniforms and one is mapping them to textures. And then I can iterate over the uniforms and then get the respective texture. So no pointless Iterator objects are created but I am also not having any duplicates :)